# bootstrap icons not displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded the image for bootstraps icons and I would like to use them in a web page

I have the image, and the correct CSS

But they arent displaying anything at all.

CSS

```
.icon-home {
  background-image:url(../img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
  background-position: 0 -24px;
}
```

HTML

```
                        <div class="col">
                            <span class="icon-home"></span>
                            <p>Pittsburgh, PA 15276</p>
                        </div>
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jwct6rmk/

I uploaded the image to an imgur account.

Comment: You're not setting any width and height for that icon. It should be there, but with 0px size.

Comment: I've updated the ehight and width but still nothing. Updated fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r missing some styling.. Mainly the `display:block` on the `span` element.

Try this:

```
.icon-home {
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/UMAlj55.png);
  background-position: 0 -24px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display:block;
}
```

or better:

```
.icon {
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/UMAlj55.png);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display:block;
}

.icon-home {
  background-position: 0 -24px;
}

.icon-car {
  background-position: 0 -36px;
}

...
```

Comment: You could also change `.icon-home` to `.icon.home` and use `class="home icon"`.

Comment: the `width` and `height` should be `15px` to display the whole icon image and if you want to add text to the same line as the icon you should use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block`

Comment: @FabioG +1, however who sets the width and height for an icon anyway =) ? Nowadays we use icon-fonts inside the inlined pseudo elements. So only the font-size matters..

Comment: @Pierre true story! :)